# Does $216$ truly the only such number?

Tags: number-theory

I'm also interested in natural numbers that cannot be written as $P+n(n+1)/2$, with $P$ is either zero or prime. Would you believe it that $216$ is the only number I found that cannot be written as such up to $20000$(!). I suspect that $216$ is the only number that cannot be written as $P+n(n+1)/2$ with $P$ either zero or prime. Does there exist another natural number besides $216$ that cannot be written as such ?. Or you can prove that $216$ is indeed the only such number?

Comment: This sounds like a question for the mathematics stack exchange, and not the Mathematica SE (which is for the software Mathematica).

Comment: Also, what about 1, 36, 105, 171, 210.

Comment: Presumably, you posted that before OP edited to allow $P=0$? @evanb

Comment: I edited my comment to correct for P=0 and exclude those, but the edit didn't take when the question moved from mathematica. to math.se

Answer (score 3):

Comments at [A132399](https://oeis.org/A132399) say that this is **currently unknown**. It was [conjectured by Zhi-Wei Sun in 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3737) that $216$ is the only such number.

It is known that the next such number, if it exists, is larger than $10^{12}$.

Comment: I've checked it myself for numbers below $10^9$ (takes 77 seconds), but I don't plan to top the $10^{12}$, it's just a subnotebook.